# How to view output from server in shiny modules?

Tags: r, shiny

I tried to create a simple modules based on an example. However, I am unable to view the output. I guess something is wrong with how I am using `callModule`. I was also wondering how to use `moduleServer` instead. I tried using `import` and `contents` as `id` but I feel that didn't work.

```
library(shiny)

importUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
  
}

importSE <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  importUI("import")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  callModule(importSE, "import")
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here's a link to an example [.csv file](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/vcd/UKSoccer.csv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ns()` function in your `importUI()` function when naming your elements. It should look like

```
importUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File", accept = ".csv"),
    checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
    tableOutput(ns("contents"))
  )
  
}
```

The same thing applies if you use the module server. But in that case you wouldn't need `importSE` any more, you'd use

```
myModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, 
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        file <- input$file1
        ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
      
        req(file)
        validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
        read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

and then in your server function you would have

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  myModuleServer("import")
}
```